# Returning iterators and combining them

Tags: rust

New to Rust and I have the following code for parsing a query in Actix that constructs a bunch of keys to query Redis:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct RouteRequest {
    proto: String,
    ids: Option<String>,
    aliases: Option<String>
}

fn get_redis_keys_from_ids(ids: Option<&String>) -> Vec<String> {
    match ids {
        None => vec!{},
        Some(s) => s.split(",").map(|s| "id:".to_owned() + s).collect()
    }
}

fn get_redis_keys_from_aliases(aliases: Option<&String>) -> Vec<String> {
    match aliases {
        None => vec!{},
        Some(s) => s.split(",").map(|s| "aid:".to_owned() + s).collect()
    }
}

fn get_redis_keys(req: web::Form<RouteRequest>) -> Vec<String> {
    let ids = get_redis_keys_from_ids(req.ids.as_ref());
    let aliases = get_redis_keys_from_aliases(req.aliases.as_ref());

    ids.into_iter().chain(aliases.into_iter()).collect()
}
```

Basically, if I have the following data:

```
RouteRequest {
  ids: "foo,bar"
  aliases: "baz,crux"
}
```

Then the vector returned by `get_redis_keys()` should be:

```
{"id:foo", "id:bar", "aid:baz", "aid:crux"}
```

What would be the cleanest and most efficient way of writing this code? Currently, I do this mapping of `Option<String>` to `Option<&String>` not sure if that's necessary, since I could just take ownership of the `Option`? I'm also returning `Vec`s from the helper functions, which causes unnecessary heap allocations.

In other words, how do I write this code in a better way avoiding unnecessary allocations? Trying to learn some Rust here.

Comment: Not more efficient but alternative: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46c35b28474237017c66bac89cb8586f

Comment: Your alternative can be a bit simplified to the following: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6883831d6286a7884c3e81225567d1d6

Comment: Not sure which one is better though. :)

Comment: I'd suggest receiving an `Option<&str>`, and using `.as_deref()`. You can also potentially reduce the string allocations in each iteration by preallocating a string with the right length, i.e. `let t = String::with_capacity(key.len() + s.len()); t.push_str(key); t.push_str(s);`. This is guaranteed to allocate only once, while `key.to_owned() + s` will potentially allocate twice.